# Creating a 3D effect Rectangle Shape

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to draw rectangle like 3D on 2D screen like below image

[image]

The rectangle shape is:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="500dp"
                android:height="250dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#03a9f4"
                android:centerColor="#00e5ff"
                android:endColor="#00e676"
                android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>
```

but i can't show like above image

Comment: you cannot do that in xml - you need `Canvas` API for that

Comment: how can i do it sir can you give me some example sir @pskink

Comment: I fail to see something which can be defined 3D, here. I only see a 2D ticket with a pseudo-shadow hovering over a background. All 2D elements.

Comment: ahh thank's you sir you notice my mistake can you tell me sir how can i draw it on xml file sir @NoiseGenerator

Comment: read about `BlurMaskFilter` and `LinearGradient` for example

Comment: Probably, it's easier to use a **9 patch**. Note: you would normally expect the shadow to be projected on the bottom-right side, since (typically - not always true) the light comes from the upper-left side.

Comment: When using material design, you don't need a 9patch or a canvas. Given the example in the question, you can use [shadows](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) for it

Comment: @Zoe not really as the shadow is less visible when going from left to right

Comment: And... do you have to compulsively stay chained to Material design?

Comment: tq all of you sir your suggested are helpful me tq all :)